# Aws Programmatic launch batch job

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-batch

Hey I have the following function to launch a batch job.

My batch job has two parameters to be passed in
--source
--destination

```
def kickoff_transfer_batch(self,item):
    try:
        batch = boto3.client('batch')
        bucket, key = get_s3_bucket_and_key(item.source)
        jobName = 'transfer-'+ key
        jobQueue = 'aws-strikeforce-on-demand-restore-prod'
        jobDefinition = 'aws-strikeforce-transfer-prod'
        source = '--source ' + item.source
        destination ='--destination ' + item.destination

        command = []
        command.append(source)
        command.append(destination)

        submit_job_response = batch.submit_job(
            jobName=jobName,
            jobQueue=jobQueue,
            jobDefinition=jobDefinition,
            containerOverrides={'command': command}
        )
        job_id = submit_job_response['jobId']
        print('Submitted job {} {} to the job queue {}'.format(jobName, job_id, jobQueue))
    except Exception as err:
        item.errored = True
        print("failed: " + item.source)
        print("error: " + str(err))
        stack_trace = traceback.format_exc()
        self._log_error_notes(item.source, err, stack_trace)
```

My job is being launched from batch, but my container is failing to launch due to how I am passing in --source and --dest.
Here is the error log

```
main.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --source file_test.txt --destination file_test.txt
```

How can I fix my command list to pass in the proper arguments.
When I launch job at the command line I would just type
--source file, --dest file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer to this for future reference

```
    def kickoff_transfer_batch(self,item):
    try:
        batch = boto3.client('batch')
        bucket, key = get_s3_bucket_and_key(item.source)
        jobName = 'transfer-'+ key
        jobQueue = 'aws-strikeforce-on-demand-restore-prod'
        jobDefinition = 'aws-strikeforce-transfer-prod'
        command = '--source '+ item.source + '--destination ' + item.destination
        command = command.split()

        submit_job_response = batch.submit_job(
            jobName=jobName,
            jobQueue=jobQueue,
            jobDefinition=jobDefinition,
            containerOverrides={'command': command}
        )
        job_id = submit_job_response['jobId']
        print('Submitted job {} {} to the job queue {}'.format(jobName, job_id, jobQueue))
    except Exception as err:
        item.errored = True
        print("failed: " + item.source)
        print("error: " + str(err))
        stack_trace = traceback.format_exc()
        self._log_error_notes(item.source, err, stack_trace)
```

Comment: What is the item variable of type?

Comment: Don't you also have to send the python script as part of the command? like containerOverrides={'command': ['python_script.py', arguments]}?